# SQL - Call a proc or function where user enters two table names

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I cannot seem to find an answer for my question or even if its possible, I want to create a function or procedure that asks the user for two table names something like Table A and Table B

```
call myfunction(table_a, table_b)
or
call myprocedure(table_a, table_b)
```

inside each table contains addresses and i've created a script to tear the address to parts and try to match them together, but i only want to produce the call function above.

each table structure would have the same structure

```
SELECT *   FROM (SELECT KEY_A
               ,ADDRESS_LINE
               ,POSTCODE
               ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KEY_A ORDER BY ADDRESS_LINE) ADDRESS_LINE_RN
           FROM TABLE_NAME) A  
WHERE ADDRESS_LINE_RN = 1    AND LENGTH(TRIM(ADDRESS_LINE)) > 0    AND LENGTH(TRIM(POSTCODE)) > 0
```

Is this even possible? I just want to keep the end user experience easy and fast.

Many Thanks

Comment: you use dynamic sql for that https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm but why have you two tables with the same design, that seems very inefficient

Comment: hi, i dont think you understood my question, both tables contain addresses, im trying to match those two tables together using those address

Comment: your code has no where 2 tables

Comment: OH CRAP, sorry that was supposed to say table_a, table_b

Comment: the answer is nit complete but it shows what i meant by my comment, you conatinate the table names in to a sql string a and The JOIN SELECT table:a and table_b on what ever lkey and then you can find equal rows or whatever

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure select_table (name1 varchar2) is
begin
execute immediate 'select * from '||name1;
end;
```

Here is the code but u wont  see any output u need to put the result in a variable or in a collection and then loop through collection to output the result, or u can create a pipelined table function like this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_table (name1 VARCHAR2)
    RETURN YOUR_OBJECT%ROWTYPE PIPELINED IS
        TYPE t_sql_result IS
            TABLE OF your_object%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
        sql_result t_sql_result;
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
        'SELECT * FROM (SELECT KEY_A ,ADDRESS_LINE ,POSTCODE ,ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER(PARTITION BY KEY_A ORDER BY ADDRESS_LINE) ADDRESS_LINE_RN FROM '||name1||')
        A WHERE ADDRESS_LINE_RN = 1 AND LENGTH(TRIM(ADDRESS_LINE)) > 0 AND LENGTH(TRIM(POSTCODE)) > 0'
                BULK COLLECT INTO sql_result;
        FOR I IN sql_result.FIRST..sql_result.LAST LOOP
            PIPE ROW (T_sql_result(I.FIRST_COLUMN,I.SECOND_COLUMN...));
        END LOOP;
        RETURN;
    END;
    
    SELECT * FROM TABLE(select_table('table_name'));
```

Comment: hi, im trying to understand whats the script doing but i'm struggling to see where it would ask the user for the 2nd table, the purpose of this is to be able to match two tables together using those address. thanks

Comment: the script is a guide not a precise code, you should adjust it to your needs it should be easy. Just make another parameter in function and concatenate the table name to your sql dynamic query in the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement and don t forget to create a database level object that corresponds to the output record